# What is the best word to describe a thing is large, complicated and intelligent?

Tags: meaning, american-english, demonstratives

I am writing a description for our product to present in a small demonstration next week. I've built a system that serves people to save time and utilize/optimize their work. I intend to write about that system like **"a large, complicated and intelligent system"**, but I feel it's quite non-sense, rough and not attractive much to people. Can anyone suggest me a word, or term to let people think about it **not only smart, helpful, insightful but also large and complicated**? (Because our 10 man team has built it for over 1.5 year).  Thank you so much.

Comment: If you've got a system that could be meaningfully described as "insightful", I think you should contact some [Artificial Intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) researchers (and apply for your Nobel prize, which should be a shoe-in! :)

Comment: _Monolithic_?  Maybe with additional qualifiers like _intuitive_ or _high-level_...

Comment: I agree: you should not refer to your system as intelligent, either, i feel, as it is merely "good" (one would hope) rather than actually sentient.  Marketing people may describe software as intelligent but you shouldn't if you want people to take you seriously as a scientist/engineer.

Comment: @trpt4him Monolithic is quite insulting for software isn't it?  It usually means that it's impossible to make any adjustments to it without breaking it: sort of the opposite of *modular*.

Comment: :) Yeap, you can ignore the word "insightful" in above description, I just wanted to say this system can "understand" & serve users' needs quite well, from their usual behavior to the long-complex workflow they may operate on this. Just didn't know "insightful" can't be applied to a non-human thing.

Comment: What about [*sophisticated*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/sophisticated) ? Example: Developing a sophisticated and secure point-of-sale (POS) terminal can be a challenge.

Comment: @Max Williams, you might be right -- large and complex together, to me, imply a system that is very rigid, which leads me to _monolithic_.  As for whether it's an insult or not may depend on context.

Comment: @Đinh Hồng Châu: In loose parlance we all tend to say things like *The computer **says** No*, but by the time you start saying computers ***think*** or ***understand*** anything, you're definitely moving further into territory that's still a distant dream for AI researchers (who've probably already spent *$billions* not getting very far in that direction).

Comment: You may be proud of how complex it is and that you got it to work, but customers don’t necessarily care- they just want it to work seamlessly and nonintrusively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Complicated" is a bad word because (as a software engineer myself), to me that means "difficult to maintain" or "difficult to use".

Similarly, the word "large" can also be applied to a great deal of really crappy software that fills people's computers up without great benefit.  I would avoid that too.

Basically, "large" and "complicated" are two words that a manager of a development team would use to warn her team that they were about to tackle an unpleasant job, and even though you're talking about communicating with customers the language will cross over:  some of your customers are probably software-savvy themselves.

"Intelligent" is just a lie.  Humans are (sometimes) intelligent.  Computers are not, and software is not, despite the claims of marketing people.

Instead of "complicated", you could say "**sophisticated**".

Instead of "large", you could say "**full-featured**" or "**wide-ranging**".

Instead of "intelligent", you could say "**intuitive**", although this is referring to how easy it is for someone to learn how to use the software, rather than how good it is.  But, i think the previous suggestions cover this anyway.